Looking for name of old sci fi show - trapped on mysterious Island
I remember seeing a show in the early 80's that I would like to see again out of pure nostalgia - I was a young kid at the time. Unfortunately I cannot remember much of the show so I hope the few things I have might trigger some suggestions.
I remember something about an single propeller engine plane similar to a Cesna being stopped in midair by a mysterious force and forced down on some mysterious island with a family that then tried to escape that island. There was also a robot and it might be similar to Robby the Robot or BB-9. As I remeber it the scene with the "frozen" airplane was part of the start of the episodes.
I do not recall it had anything to do with space ..this was solely based on Earth and it was quite low budget. It was an american show - in color and I'm guessing it is from the late 70's. The show itself was either set in "present" time or very near future.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give?Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

I'll try to add more but as I was a little boy not much is left - I know it's a long shot but I thought there was no harm in trying.
